# How do I set up an icon (drawable) for a button in anko?

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I want to have an icon in the centre of a plain button, using anko. I tried

`button.backgroundResource = R.drawable.arrow_forward`

but I got drawable covering whole button and getting background colour from its parent (setting background colour on button explicite does nothing).

[image]

I tried  `drawable = ...` as well, with same effect. How do I set up an icon with anko to have original aspect ratio and be centered?

Comment: Don't use the background. That will always make it stretch the entire view bounds. Other than that, look for a way to set the ScaleType. You probably want centerInside or fitCenter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone else is still trying to achieve this, here's a guide:

1. Create an extension function (perhaps in a standalone `.kt` file or in your `Activity` or `Fragment` class file where you want to use the button) like so:

```
inline fun ViewManager.materialButton(@StyleRes theme: Int, init: MaterialButton.() -> Unit = {}): MaterialButton {
    return ankoView({ MaterialButton(it) }, theme, init = init)
}
```

2. Then use your button like other Anko views, like so:

```
materialButton(R.style.App_ThemeOverlay /** some overlay theme **/) {
  icon = context.getDrawable(R.drawable.arrow_forward)
  // ... other regular and material button properties here ...
}
```

Answer (score 4):

First off, in order to set an Icon/image on a Button you should use `ImageButton`.

Then it's easy.

```
imageButton{
     imageResource = R.drawable.ic_cc_checkmark
}
```

If you need to use other resources or a drawable, then to get it without getting a Resource not found Error use `ctx.getDrawable(R.x.y)`

Hope this helps someone

Comment: well, I need to accept it as the answer, and ask another question - I originally intended to have either an image or a text on a button, depending on the state of the app - that's why I asked about setting image for a button. Finally I ended up having two buttons (image and plain) and hiding/showing them accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how Anko is supposed to work.
Technically for android, assuming you have an image button you should do :

```
((ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.yourButtonID)).setImageResource(R.drawable.yourDrawable);
```

Comment: thank you, I just should have used ImageButton. Initially I just wanted to use one plain button and set an icon or a text on it, depending on the state. Using two buttons and showing/hiding them seems to be the easiest solution.
I couldn't get `scaleType` to work with background, and `drawableTop|Bottom` etc. wouldn't suit my needs as well, so I'll stick with what I have now.
Still, I don't know if that should be accepted answer.

Comment: You mean you can't get scaleType to work on an ImageButton ?

Comment: no, I couldn't get scaleType to work on plain button (i.e., there's just no such property). ImageButton worked as expected straight out from the box and there was no need to scale the image at all. I'll edit my question accordingly, though it seem it probably was answered numerous times then

Comment: I should perhaps scale the drawable to have proper height relative to the button, proper width resulting from aspect ratio and then set it as `backgroundDrawable`. I'll explore it some day later